# Adding conditions to CodeIgniter Query

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am currently trying to access a MongoDB database where dob is stored as a string like '01/30/2016'. I am trying to write a page that will obtain the results based on age. I have no way of changing how the data is stored in the database, and only can make select queries. The select code works its just the where calls for age that do not work. I have tried the following and it has not worked.

```
$date = strtotime(date('07/13/1991'));
//age 25 years old
this->db->where_lt(strtotime('birthdate'), $date);
//This makes it so nothing returns, the _lt or _gt doesn't matter because I
//instances of both.
```

Are you able to make a query using a modified field? Any help would be greatly appreciated and most importantly have a great day!

EDIT 1:
I have been experimenting more with it, but still haven't gotten it. Is there a way to have the first parts of $date be considered everything? Then it would just be comparing the year which is what I want.

EDIT 2:
After asking some friends they said that $regex may be able to help me, but they were not sure. Does anyone know if $regex can help me in this case?

Comment: They produce the same output.

Comment: This is not clear what u actually want.Make it clear so that i can help you Do you want select all data that have age less than or gerater than or want to select all data where date is greater or less

Comment: I am going to want both eventually. The main thing is when I have $date = 07/13/1991, and the field 'birthdate' = 02/14/1989; If I do this->db->where_lt('birthdate', $date) it will evaluate it off the month, where I need to evaluate it off the year(at the very least). What I need is a way to enable it so it will evaluate the whole string as a date, or at the very least just the year. So whichever one is easier for you to explain, I will hopefully be able to figure out the other one.